# Website driving CPU Usage high and causing system fan to run full speed

Tags: google-chrome

When I open this website, my CPU usage spikes and my system fan runs at full speed. I searched for information about this website, but did not get any information online.  Is this website doing crypto mining using my cpu? Or is this some kind of a malware site?

https://yourdiy.com/box-office-flops/

I pressed F12 and checked Network. It has a lot of entries. I was expecting to see a websocket connection or a wasm running. But did not find one. But I am not able to identify something which could drive my cpu usage. This was done in Chrome browser